# Python Selenium how to click on xpath with svg , id , g , path

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

I wanna write code to click on path to download excel file
it consist of  svg , id , g , path , I am unable to click on path

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import time as t
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)

big_df = pd.DataFrame()

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
chrome_options.add_argument('disable-notifications')
chrome_options.add_argument("window-size=1280,720")

webdriver_service = Service("chromedriver/chromedriver") ## path to where you saved chromedriver binary
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=webdriver_service, options=chrome_options)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 25)

url = 'https://www.edelweissmf.com/types-of-mutual-funds/bharat-bond-funds/edelweiss-etf-bharat-bond-2023'
driver.get(url)

driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 1200);")    # NOt getting scrolled
                            
abc= wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='flex item-center']//*[name()='svg' and @id='Capa_1']//*[name()='g']//*[name()='path']")))


    
abc.click()
```

How to clock on path by using selenium ?
I am trying to clock on path by using xpath with svg , id , g , path  from the html code
but I am unable to download desired excel file in PORTFOLIO section of page and file of LHS of debt

UPDATE:-

My Program is working , just need to scroll page upward and its not working
or I will have to Click on " Portfolio" mentioned in Green which will move the webpage.

Comment: How can _`//div[@class='flex item-center']//*[name()='svg' and @id='Capa_1']//*[name()='g']//*[name()='path']`_ be a _CSS_SELECTOR_? Which element are you trying to click?

Comment: Firstly you need to change CSS_SELECTOR to XPATH ans @undetectedSelenium mentioned. Secondly, your page html contains `shadow-root` in the dom. You need to handle shadow-root in order to locate the element you want to capture

Comment: @Manish I have already seen the DOM and I know that :) OP needs to know whats happening at the backyard so he understands the actual issue. Else they would come back again and again with the same issue, which we want to avoid at any cost.

Comment: @undetectedSelenium if u open url and scroll down ( else on green scale , you will see "Portfolio", just click on it will be scolled down to portfolio) ,  there we can wee one excel file . I wanna download it.

Comment: @undetectedSelenium I just saw that , if I change CSS_Selector to XPATH it will work only when i click on "Portfolio" ( in that green tab) and scroll page downward......I think to work program scrolling is required ( which is not working ) or have to click on " Portfolio" so that it will get scrolled down

Comment: Thanks all I did it by adding ........element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//ul[@class='flex item-center flex-end']//li[ text()='Portfolio']")))
and 
element.click()

Comment: See @Manish even I thought OP wants to click on Download button which wasn't the case. Thats why we need certain clarity on the question. Else there is high chace we answer something elsewhich would not be helpful to OP.

Comment: How same thing can be done without using selenium ?  I don't like to use selenium as its too slow